# Eclipse Mac to Windows notepad formatting no carriage return

Tags: java, ide, code-formatting

I am using eclipse on mac to do my java coding.

Now i need to open a .java file that was created with mac eclipse and open it in a Windows notepad.

However all the carriage return/ newline formatting is gone.

Is there a way where I can retain all the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows notepad is not able to display linebreaks other than the ones used in Windows (CR+LF, Unix-Systems use LF only). If you have to open it in a built-in Editor like Notepad, try WordPad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change line endings preferences go to:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> New text file line delimiter.
```

If you want to convert line endings to windows format, read [this post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031018164326986) for doing it with flip.

Otherwise I will recommend you to use other text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) on windows.

Regards.